# Фонетика и "звучание"  - есть разница?

Tags: фонетика

Мы все более или менее представляем, что такое фонетика русского (или любого другого языка). Попросту говоря, это набор используемых языком фонем - и правила их произнесения.

Возникает вопрос. А что тогда "звучание" языка?

Я про то "звучание", по которому можно, например, безошибочно определить, что человек говорит по-русски "абсолютно правильно, но с акцентом" или что, скажем, немецкий язык больше похож на русский, чем китайский. Причем сравнить близость русского, украинского и, скажем, польского способен даже человек, этими языками совсем не владеющий. При том, что собственно фонетика всех трех достаточно близка, а такие детали, как редуцирование гласных в русском или носовые в польском, человеком, языками не владеющим, на слух не воспринимается.

Вот некоторый самый простой набор факторов, которое к фонетике - русской по крайней мере - не относятся, но безусловно относятся к "звучанию" языка: "музыкальный" строй (повышение-понижение интонации), паузы, логическое ударение, быстрота речи, отчасти даже - мимика и жестикуляция... Но вряд ли это главное, видимо есть что-то гораздо более существенное, которое и хочется "отловить".

ЗЫ Изначально вопрос возник не в связи с русским языком, поэтому вопрос не об очевидных для русского деталях, а о каком-то системном подходе, если таковой здесь можно навести.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем.
Плсле некоторого размышления и не вашей без помощи, я понял, как надо было сформулировать вопрос - и сразу же нашелся ответ.
Фонетика - вещь объективная, это то о чем столь подробно рассказала **Ларf**. Звучание - субъективно воспринимаемая устная речь. Субъективность проявляется в неформализуемых подсознательных отношениях слушающего субъекта к звуковому потоку, основанных на опыте, представлениях о гармонии, музыкальности субъекта, степени знакомства с данным и близкими языками - и много на чем ещё.

Предыстория вопроса была такова. Говорили (на Грамоте) о каталанском языке. Моим собеседником было высказано негативное отношение к цитате "Каталанский звучит как французский". Попытка найти **объективное** подтверждение или опровержение не увенчалась успехом. Дело в том, что мой оппонент критиковал высказывание именно с позиций объективной фонетики (и в такой постановке был, видимо, прав). А автор высказывания говорил явно о собственных ощущениях.

"Автором" высказывания, если верить цитирующему (я сам не проверял), был Пётр Львович Вайль.

Лично мне язык (звучание) показался похожим на португальский. 
Короче говоря, вывод такой, что *звучание* языка - вещь субъективная. Говорить о том, что язык А звучит подобно языку Б можно лишь с позиций собственного ощущения. Тем самым опровергать чьё-либо мнение, с вашим обычно не совпадающее, это сродни спору о вкусе ананасов с теми, кто их не пробовал.

Правильный ответ не выбираю, ибо правы все.

Comment: Не приписывайте мне чужих заслуг. Это Людмила.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.langust.ru/review/lang_h04.shtml
То, о чём Вы говорите, относится тоже к фонетике. Имеются три стороны звуков речи, и им соответствуют три раздела фонетики: акустика речи, антропофоника или физиология речи, фонология(изучает функцию или роль звуков в языке).

Звуковые единицы языка могут быть сегментными (линейными) и суперсегментными.
Сегментные единицы - это звуки (фонемы), слоги, слова и т.д. 
Суперсегментные единицы, или иначе просодические (от греч. prosodia - припев, ударение) наслаиваются на цепочку сегментов - слогов, слов, фраз, предложений. Типичные суперсегментные единицы - ударение и интонация.

•Такт - группа слов, объединенных одним ударением и отделенных друг от друга паузой.
(Проклитика,энклитика )

•Ударение -силовое (динамическое),количественное ,музыкальное (политоническое).

•Тон — ритмико-мелодический рисунок речи, определяющийся изменением частоты звукового сигнала.
•Темп — скорость речи, которая определяется количеством сегментных единиц, произнесенных за единицу времени.

•Длительность — время звучания сегмента речи.

В фонетике есть и понятие звуковедения : способ связи звуков в процессе фонации. 
Основные виды звуковедения: связное (legato) и дискретное (staccato, non legato).

Тип фонации:  открытый глоттис - 
нейтральный голос (воздух проходит свободно)- во всех языках,
придыхательная фонация - звонкие придыхательные согласные(хинди),слабый голос -слабые согласные(яванский),модальный голос (максимальная амплитуда)-звонкие согласные(русский),
напряжённый голос -напряжённые согласные(тайский),скрипучий голос - скрипучие согласные
(бирманский);Закрытый глоттис- гортанный приступ (воздух не проходит)   гортанная смычка
(Ненецкий)

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/

Comment: >То, о чём Вы говорите, относится тоже к фонетике. 
  
Я вообще-то и сам не знаю, о чем я говорю, как раз пытаюсь понять что именно является причиной "звучания". Так что Ваше утверждение несколько спорное. 
В остальном - спасибо. Я попозжк прокомментрирую.

Comment: Я сам догадаюсь, о чем мне спрашивать. Вот если бы Вы с вашей способностью на любые вопросы давать *любые* ответы помогли с формулировкой. Но похоже, Вы опять о чем-то своем...

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что нужно выделить как минимум два уровня восприятия. Первый - на уровне звуков. Понятно, что если мы слышим незнакомый язык, то мы с трудом сможем разбить речь на нем на слова и предложения. Тем более, если говорят достаточно быстро. Но по ощущению от звуковой структуры можно угадать язык. Второй - на уровне слов. Человеческий мозг пытается вычленять знакомые структуры. Так могу привести пример, что мальчик просил отца поставить песенку про лошадку, а по факту это была итальянская песня "La Shate Mi Cantare". Причем это уже практически баян ([1](http://www.rodim.ru/conference/lofiversion/index.php/t15510-500.html), [2](http://nasimov.uz/2010/12/0119-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8/)). Тут получилось, что в иностранной песне нашли элементы, схожие с родным языком. Честно говоря, если говорят быстро или невнятно, то и на родном языке не всегда разберешь, о чем говорят... На принципе похожести различных слов и фраз построено огромное количество роликов из серии [Misheard Lyrics](http://lurkmore.to/Misheard_lyrics). Поискать можно на YouTube.  Как только человек узнает какие-то слова иностранного языка (а это сплошь и рядом происходит), то он может узнавать что это за язык. Причем проблема в том, что это все происходит как сознательно, так и на бессознательно, что усугляет сложность вопроса.

P.S. лимит по количеству символов в комментарии я превысил. Сорри.

Comment: >P.S. лимит по количеству символов в комментарии я превысил. Сорри.  
  
Зато получили парочку вполне заслуженных плюсиков.

Answer (score 2):

Акценты мы различаем, по манере произносить звуки, на манер своего языка, или слишком правильно и академично строит фразы, если владеет языком в совершенстве.
Если говорить об определении близости незнакомого языка, то думаю, тут основным компонентом является ритм речи. У жёстко ритмизованного рэпа определить язык довольно непросто, а мелодичных песнях и живой речи особенности произношения слышны без проблем. Также без знания языка слышна специфика ударения, и азиатское тоновое, можно определить всегда.